# Wcf Service, I'm getting this error: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8

Tags: c#, wcf, service

Wcf Service, I'm getting this error: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding

Comment: Please add more information to your question. Add the code in question, as well as the full exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this error when you try to get response from WCF service that on https, but your bindings are set to basicHttpBinding on your application web config. Change your bindings from `<basicHttpBinding>` to `<basicHttpsBinding>`.

It might solve your problem.

Comment: How can I add to appsettings.json?